# Error in RSS Feed structure. Strange 'element' <head/>. Where to look?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I just found when trying to use IFTTT that my blog's wordpress feed seems to be faulty: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kallmeyer-naturheilpraxis.de%2Ffeed

There appears to a strange element in the beginning.

I am by no means a programmer but this is a great point to start learning php. Unfortunately after checking most of the wordpress php that they are as they should be.

So now I have no idea where to look else. I did download all php files locally and tried to search for this element - nothing.

It would be nice if someone could put back on track where possibly to look for the bug.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of wordpress? Any plugins?

Comment: check your  `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php` first 25 lines or so. Check for anything funky. Proper looks like https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php